# Can we claim that $\cot x$ is decreasing on $x\in(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2)$ except for the point $x=0$ in which the function is not defined?

Tags: trigonometry, monotone-functions

We know that the derivative of $\cot x$ with respect to $x$ is $-\csc^2 x$. Then, since $-\csc^2 x<0$ is negative except for integer multiples of $\pi$, therefore, can we claim that the function $\cot x$ is decreasing over the interval $(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2)$ except for the point $x=0$ for which the function is not defined?

[image]

Comment: No. It is decreasing on $(-\pi/2,0)$ though (and on $(0,\pi/2)$).

Comment: [You asked a nearly-identical question already.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4276076/409) Re-posting is not the appropriate way to draw more attention to a question; rather, you should edit the original to improve its quality or sharpen its focus. If you believe this question differs enough from the original to be considered a separate question (which may be true), you should explain the differences and also explain what you found unsatisfactory about the response the response the original received, so that people don't waste their time duplicating unhelpful information.

Comment: I see now that you have deleted your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4276076/409). Doing so is inconsiderate to the person who took time to provide an answer. (It also increases the likelihood that someone will provide an equally-unsatisfactory answer *here* because they cannot see what you were told before.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A function $f$ is decreasing on $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if for every $x$ and $y$ in $D$, we have that $x≤y \Rightarrow f(x)≥f(y)$.

---

So for $D = \left( - \frac{π}{2}, 0\right)\cup \left(0, \frac{π}{2}\right) $, choosing $x \in \left(-\frac{π}{2}, 0\right)$ and $y \in \left(0, \frac{π}{2} \right)$ with $f(x)= \cot x$, you'd have, $x≤y \Rightarrow f(x)≤f(y)$.

So does that mean $f$ is increasing? No. Choose $x$ and $y$ from $\left(-\frac{π}{2},0\right)$ and see for yourself.

Well then what in the world is it? Well $f$ is a neither increasing nor decreasing (or non-monotonic) function on $D$.

---

There's a good lesson to learn from this— that it is meaningless to say a function is increasing or decreasing without mentioning where. For instance, our $f$ is indeed decreasing on the intervals $ \left( - \frac{π}{2}, 0\right)$ and $ \left(0, \frac{π}{2}\right)$ but just not on both of them together.